# Binding C-M-g to keyboard quit

Tags: emacs

I am trying to map `C-M-g` to the same functionality as `C-g` however if I, for example, press `M-x` and then `C-M-g` the minibuffer says Quit, and then goes back to the M-x menu

Comment: This doesn't tell us what you've actually done.  Show us the code.

Comment: I *suspect* that you've added a binding to `keyboard-quit` in the global keymap, and not realised that there are multiple keymaps in which `C-g` is bound.  In your example `M-x` scenario, `C-g` runs the command `abort-recursive-edit`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5971/454 might be a sensible approach.